# UserData giving timeout error while accessing s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to access an object from S3 public bucket but I am getting below error while executing my Cfn-init helper script:

> ConnectionError Traceback (most recent call last): File "cfnbootstrap\util.pyc", line 162, in _retry File "cfnbootstrap\util.pyc", line 234, in _timeout ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))"

I can access the S3 bucket if I RDP the instance and change proxy settings in browser.

Below is my code:

```
 "Resources": {
    "WebServer": {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication": {
                "S3AccessCreds": {
                    "type": "S3",
                    "roleName": "sit-test-user",
                    "buckets" : ["sit-test-bucket"]
                }
            },
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                "config": {
                    "sources": {
                        "c:\\S3\\xxxx" : "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx.ps1"
                    }
                }
            }
        },



"UserData" : {
              "Fn::Base64" : { 
                  "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                  "<script>\n",
                    "cfn-init.exe -s ", 
                    {"Ref" : "AWS::StackId"}, 
                    " -r WebServer --region ", 
                    {"Ref" : "AWS::Region"},
                    " --http-proxy http://proxy.aws.xxxxxx.local:8080 \n",
                "</script>\n"
                ]]
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, down to the same error line numbers. In my case, I was launching my instance into a private subnet and then trying to execute various configuration commands and downloads from S3 (without a VPC endpoint) in UserData. But, my subnet had no route to the Internet. To fix this I did:

- In my CloudFormation template added a route-table association to a route table pointing to the NAT gateway:

> ```
> AssocANat:
> Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
> DependsOn:
>   - SubnetA
>   - RouteTableNATGatewayA
> Properties:
>   RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTableNATGatewayA
>   SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
> ```

- Added an outbound security group rule to allow TCP 443 and whatever else my UserData needed:

> ```
> SecurityGroupEgress:
> - IpProtocol: tcp
>   FromPort: '443'
>   ToPort: '443'
>   CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
> ```